# Retrieve images from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, memorystream

I have a question that when I retrieve image from database from memory stream it gives an error `Parameter is not valid`. Please help me out from this problem.

Code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string strcon = "Data Source=PINKAL-PC; initial catalog=testing; integrated security=SSPI;";

   SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strcon);
   sqlcon.Open();

   string strquery = "select * from testimg";

   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strquery,sqlcon);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds);

   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt = ds.Tables[0];

   byte[] barrImg = (byte[])dt.Rows[7]["image"];
   MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(barrImg);

   pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream);
}
```

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: What **columns** does your table `testimg` contain?? Most likely, you've just misspelled the column name when you access the data.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the actual root cause of your problem is - my guess would be that there is no column by the name of `image` in your database table `testimg`, but you're trying to read that column to get your picture.

But here are a few things I'd recommend for your code in general:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string strcon = "Data Source=PINKAL-PC; initial catalog=testing; integrated security=SSPI;";

   // Put your SqlConnection into using blocks to ensure proper disposal
   using(SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strcon))
   { 
     //  sqlcon.Open();  -- don't open it here already - open as LATE as possible....
     // for SqlDataAdapter - you don't even need to open it yourself - 
     // the data adapter will do this automatically for you
     // and **IF** you open it yourself - you also need to CLOSE it again!

     // *NEVER* use SELECT * in code !! specify the columns you want explicitly
     // string strquery = "select * from testimg";
     string strquery = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 ..... FROM dbo.testimg";  

     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strquery, sqlcon);

     //DataSet ds = new DataSet();  if you only want a single DataTable - no point in having a  whole DataSet ! That's just overhead.....
     //da.Fill(ds);
     //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     //dt = ds.Tables[0];
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     da.Fill(dt);

     // is there a "image" column in your table?? 
     // You need to use the proper column name here!
     byte[] barrImg = (byte[])dt.Rows[7]["image"];
     MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(barrImg);

     pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream);
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem remains same and column name and database name is correct. what should i do for this.

Comment: @user721563 : can you show us the structure of your table?? The column names and data types??

Answer (score 0):

If your error is concerned with converting the image from database into stream, Just try to modify your code like this::

```
 byte[] barrImg = (byte[])dt.Rows[7]["image"];

 MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream();

 mstream .Write ( barrImg, 0, barrImg.Length );       
 mstream .Seek ( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );        
 mstream .Close();

 pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to access the object from a closed stream? How is this suppose to work?